# Pom.xml has the frontend-maven-plugin, won't recognize bower

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, hibernate, maven

Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.edi.proiecte</groupId>
<artifactId>Livada</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>Livada</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/exec-maven-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-dependency-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars.npm/bower -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars.npm/bower -->

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <!-- optional -->
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>client</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>bower install</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>bower</goal>
                </goals>

                <configuration>
                    <!-- optional: The default argument is actually
                    "install", so unless you need to run some other bower command,
                    you can remove this whole <configuration> section.
                    -->
                    <arguments>install</arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>

            <execution>
                <id>grunt build</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>grunt</goal>
                </goals>

                <!-- optional: the default phase is "generate-resources" -->
                <phase>generate-resources</phase>

                <configuration>
                    <!-- optional: if not specified, it will run Grunt's default
                    task (and you can remove this whole <configuration> section.) -->
                    <arguments>build</arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <!-- optional -->
            <configuration>
                <installDirectory>C:\Program Files\nodejs</installDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}/client</directory>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is my pom.xml. I am trying to deploy a template to a Tomcat server, and then make a basic CRUD example for the client with angular for the frontend, hibernate for persisting objects in the database. I have created my project using the spring initializr that they provide online at https://start.spring.io/ Basically what i have to do is demonstrate a simple proof of concept to the client. My problem is the config file for maven. I am trying to use the frontend-maven-plugin to run grunt and bower and build my project into a WAR file that I can deploy on a Tomcat server. I have been fiddling around with the config file for 2 days trying to get it to work, and I have to get the thing going for today at 02:00 PM when the client will come in to see what we have done. I have made some progress, but I still get an error when bower is supposed to install:

> Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.4:bower (bower install) on project Livada: Failed to run task: 'bower install' failed. java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node\node.exe" (in directory "E:\IntelliJ_IDEA\projects\LIVADA\client"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified -> [Help 1]

Been resolving a lot of cryptic errors like this, but from what I can see, I did just like the Github page of the creator showed me to configure the frontend maven plugin: https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin

Sometimes IntelliJ even sabotaged me and would not want to run some goals, so I had to Invalidate Caches and restart the IDE.

I made another post 2 days ago, and I tried to follow the instructions that have been given in the response as close as I could, but to no avail.

[Spring + Hibernate + Angular + Maven + Tomcat Project folder structure issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44686149/spring-hibernate-angular-maven-tomcat-project-folder-structure-issues/44692309#44692309)

My project structure is as follows:

```
LIVADA - E:\IntelliJ_IDEA\projects\LIVADA
    .idea
        libraries
        .name
        compiler.xml
        encodings.xml
        misc.xml
        modules.xml
        workspace.xml
    .mvn
        wrapper
            maven-wrapper.jar
            maven-wrapper.properties
    client
        .idea
            misc.xml
            modules.xml
            sb-admin-angular-master.iml
            workspace.xml
        app
            js
                sb-admin-2.js
            scripts
                controllers
                    chartController.js
                    form.js
                    main.js
                directives
                    chat
                        chat.html
                        chat.js
                    dashboard
                        stats
                            stats.html
                            stats.js
                    header
                        header-notification
                            header-notofication.html
                            header-notification.js
                        header.html
                        header.js
                    notifications
                        notifications.html
                        notifications.js
                    sidebar
                        sidebar-search
                            sidebar-search.html
                            sidebar-search.js
                        sidebar.html
                        sidebar.js
                    timeline
                        timeline.html
                        timeline.js
                app.js
            styles
                main.css
                sb-admin-2.css
                timeline.css
            views
                dashboard
                    home.html
                    main.html
                pages
                    blank.html
                    login.html
                ui-elements
                    buttons.html
                    grid.html
                    icons.html
                    notifications.html
                    panels-wells.html
                    typography.html
                chart.html
                form.html
                table.html
            .buildignore
            .htacess
            404.html
            favicon.ico
            index.html
            robots.txt
        test
            spec
                controllers
                    about.js
                    main.js
            .jshintrc
            karma.conf.js
        .gitignore
        bower.json
        Gruntfile.js
        LICENSE
        package.json
        README.md
    src
        main
            java
                com.edi.proiecte.Livada
                    LivadaApplication.java
            resources
                application.properties
        test
            java
                com.edi.proiecte.livada
                    LivadaApplicationTests.java
        .gitignore
        Livada.iml
        mvnw
        mvnw.cmd
        pom.xml
```

Maybe I screwed up the folder structure, but i can't see how, as I configured the WAR plugin to copy files from the client folder and put them in the WAR file. Any help is greatly ppreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Solved that, for some reason the pom.xml reads C:\nodejs\node\node.exe, so i made a shortcut there. but I still get the error: Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.4:bower (bower install) on project Livada: Failed to run task: 'bower install' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

Comment: Could you try to place a link of your *nodejs* in a much easy folder like *C:\nodejs*? I think it could be the space in the path that broke.

Comment: Do I just make a shortcut of the node executable, or do I install a new instance of node there?

Comment: I think a shortjcut to the nodejs folder, not just the executable, and change accordingly your pom.xml

Comment: Solved that, for some reason the pom.xml reads C:\nodejs\node\node.exe, so i made a shortcut there. but I still get the error: Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.4:bower (bower install) on project Livada: Failed to run task: 'bower install' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

Comment: Please update the question with the new step you found.

Comment: It is bower installed globally? I mean, if you run *bower install* inside the project it works?

Comment: In Maven Projects from IntelliJ, opened the Execute Maven Goal and typed: com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.4:bower install and I get the same error. How can I install bower globally tho?

Comment: on a shell: *npm install -g bower*.

Comment: I installed bower globally. I invalidated the caches and restarted the IDE. I ran the command: bower install inside maven and got Unknown lifecycle phase "bower". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal>. Then, I typed the full goal again with: com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.4:bower install and got the same error as above.

Comment: I read the maven plugin README right now, and I found this:'Notice: This plugin does not support already installed Node or npm versions. Use the exec-maven-plugin instead.'. So you could not use your installed nodejs as you're trying to do. Instead, follow the example project. Download it and test it if it works then change your pom as described in the example project.